# VBA, New Sheet, Formating Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the follow VBA script that does an advanced filter and populates to a new sheet. I would like to get the results in order on my new sheet.

So for example Sheet 1 results would be populated in C2, Sheet 2 C3, Sheet 3 in C4. But if Sheet 2 has no results Sheet 3 will populate in  C3 instead. Anyone know of any work-around? I need the results to be correspond with the sheet. Could be a simple range formula? VBA newbie here.

```
     Sub louis4()


Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wksSummary As Excel.Worksheet
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'edited so it shows in the 3rd column row +1.  Add the header and sheet name macro to this

On Error Resume Next
Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
On Error GoTo 0

If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
    Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
End If


'Iterate through all the worksheets, but skip [Summary] worksheet.
For Each wks In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With wksSummary

        If wks.Name <> .Name Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("C:C")) Then
                Dim r As Range

     ' Get the first cell of our destination range...
       Set r = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)

     ' Perform the unique copy...
     If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("C:C")) > 1 Then
       wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
     End If

    ' Remove the first cell at the destination range...
     r.Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
        End If

    End With

     Next wks



      'Headers and sheet names
    Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
     Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
    Range("C1").Value = "Column Name"

   Dim intRow As Long: intRow = 2

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
If Sheets(i).Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
    Cells(intRow, 2) = Sheets(i).Name
    Cells(intRow, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    intRow = intRow + 1
End If
    Next i




    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you WANT or NOT WANT the result to appear in C3 from sheet 4 if c3 is blank?

Comment: Yes i want that. But to clarify, say my sheet 2 doesnt have any results.. Then I want the place its currently populating to show as a blank and not have my next sheet result to populate in that cell.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you,re doing in all of your code, at the end of this code you posted, do which variable holds the answer?

Comment: The headers and sheets name of this code doesn't matter. I just want the answers from each sheet to populate in order. So sheet 1 advanced filter results will be C2, now if sheet 2 results are not there can I put a 'N/A' or something, then sheet 3 will continue in C4. Ill show an image here :  So instead of this: [img]http://i.imgur.com/ETUM7nW.jpg[/img], I want something like this : [img]http://i.imgur.com/M3E9znY.jpg[/img]

Comment: I understand what you want to output. My qyestion was Where in your code does this occur? I assume its the result of the advanced filter that you put in r. If that's the case just write Else r = "N/A" before the End if.

Comment: yes your correct, david, could you specify where in the code to add, I added it after the `wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True` part, and get an error

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub louis4()


    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wksSummary As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LastCellInColumn As Range
    Dim NewLastCellInColumn as Range 

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
        Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
    End If


    With wksSummary

       'Headers and sheet names
        .Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
        .Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
        .Range("C1").Value = "Column Name"

        'Iterate through all the worksheets, but skip [Summary] worksheet.
        For Each wks In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

            If wks.Name <> .Name Then

                ' Get the first cell of our destination range...
                Set LastCellInColumn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).offset(1,0)

                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("C:C")) > 1 Then

                    wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , LastCellInColumn, True

                    ' Remove the first cell at the destination range...
                    ' because it contains the header text from the source sheet
                     LastCellInColumn.Delete xlShiftUp

                else

                    LastCellInColumn.value = "No data found

                End If

                Set NewLastCellInColumn  = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).offset(1,0)

                .cells(LastCellInColumn.offset(-1,0), NewLastCellInColumn.offset(-1,0)).value = wks.Name

                .cells(LastCellInColumn.offset(-2,0), NewLastCellInColumn.offset(-2,0)).value = ActiveWorkbook.Name



            End If

         Next wks

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Harvey, I get an error at the `Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")` line

Comment: @Jonathan the sheet doesn't exist.  I removed your code that created it to simplify the example.

Comment: Harvey which part did you take out? Sorry lol, how can I add your and mine together?

Comment: In my code, the bit between the first "with" and the previous Dim are different

Comment: Im not following, Would you mind altering your code to include mine?

Answer (score 0):

```
 As per what we discussed in the comments, I believe you want this:


 Sub louis4()


Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wksSummary As Excel.Worksheet
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'edited so it shows in the 3rd column row +1.  Add the header and sheet name macro to this

On Error Resume Next
Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
On Error GoTo 0

If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
    Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
End If


'Iterate through all the worksheets, but skip [Summary] worksheet.
For Each wks In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With wksSummary

        If wks.Name <> .Name Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("C:C")) Then
                Dim r As Range

     ' Get the first cell of our destination range...
       Set r = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)

     ' Perform the unique copy...
     If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("C:C")) > 1 Then
       wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
     else
       r = "N/A"
     End If

    ' Remove the first cell at the destination range...
     r.Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
        End If

    End With

     Next wks



      'Headers and sheet names
    Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
     Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
    Range("C1").Value = "Column Name"

   Dim intRow As Long: intRow = 2

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
If Sheets(i).Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
    Cells(intRow, 2) = Sheets(i).Name
    Cells(intRow, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    intRow = intRow + 1
End If
    Next i




    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help David, but still get the same as I was before lol. Sorry :(, third sheet results still going to where 2nd sheet results should be

Comment: Ok... it never writes N/A? If you debug line by line, can you tell me what r is at the moment the code enters the little part I added in? (else..)

Comment: Going through to the second sheet, I got N/A so far. but it seems to delete it when I get to r.Delete xlshift up

Comment: Ah. well, yeah. Why do you want to delete a line in the first place?

Comment: Because the header was coming through aswell as the results, so I needed to delete the header

Comment: Ah ok! Well, delete the header before the loop. Not as a part of your loop or it will try to delete it every time it loops, deleting your information as well.

Comment: So take out the `r.Delete xlshiftup`? and put it where?

Comment: First off, if you just remove it fully, does it work well now (even if it puts the header)? If yes, figure out at which point the header gets placed in with F8. Then you can add a specific condition so that it doesn't write the line if the row number is that of the header, or if the cell contains the words 'My header' or whatever. So instead of putting and removing it just doesn't write it.

Comment: I get the N/A, so that part works, but i get the headers of the other 2 sheets lol. Dam this thing is annoying

Comment: Did you try my reccomendation? To check what you're writing and skip it when it is a header?

Comment: Its after `Else r="N/A"` and on the `end if` after each loop, so use the `r.Delete xlshiftup` here?

Comment: My reccomendation is to NOT delete anything, but rather not write it in the first place. Read my previous comment.

Comment: Okay, what kind of specific condition should I put? Sorry I am newb

Comment: I can't help you that much more because I don't know what your data looks like. I don't know what [ Set r = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)] even refers to, and I don't knwo what your headers are like. If there is something different about the headers and the data, you can use that to determine whether or not you write it. If they are similar than you need to make sure the filter does not start where the headers are. I'm pretty sure that is an option of the advancedfilter (starting somewhere like row 2)